# Robotium search edittext for setError

Tags: android, text, assert, robotium

I have a txt.setError text and I want to check is the error appear on screen while on testin My testcase is;

```
solo.enterText(0, "example");
solo.clickOnImageButton(3);
assertTrue(solo.searchText("E-posta adresleri için lütfen şu biçimi kullanın: ad@example.com"));
```

[image]

I got the setError text after onclick the imagebutton

But I got AssertionFailedError
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The source of the problem was the relase of Robotium. I was using 2.1 , but for this assertion robotium 3.0 and upper is needed.

Comment: the popup, is it writting in 1 line or do you have a /n to make a new line?
You could just try to search for part of the text. like: E-posta adresleri için

Comment: No I havent got a new line. It is only one sentence

Comment: I tried for assertTrue(solo.searchText("E-posta adresleri için")); but it is give the same error. Maybe it is happening because of setError?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure popupmessages are searched, I'd add rensr on robotium google group, he is very good and quick to reply.
And ofc. come back here with answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will ask this question in Google Groups

Answer (score 2):

try using solo.waitfortext() instead of assertTrue(solo.searchText()).
the problem is probably that the assertion is executing before the text is displayed.

so i would say you have two possible options here.

Option 1:

```
solo.enterText(0, "example");
solo.clickOnImageButton(3);
solo.waitforactivity(solo.getcurrentactivity().tostring). // you will wait untill the screen is entirely displayed.
assertTrue(solo.searchText("E-posta adresleri için lütfen şu biçimi kullanın: ad@example.com"));
```

Option2 (the best option)

```
solo.enterText(0, "example");
solo.clickOnImageButton(3);
boolean textExist = solo.WaitForText("E-posta adresleri için lütfen şu biçimi kullanın: ad@example.com"));
if (!textExist){
Fail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
EditText myEditText = (android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(com.my.app.R.id.myEditText);
solo.clickOnView(myButton);

//Waits for error
solo.sleep(2000);

boolean result = myEditText.getError() == null;
if(!result){
    fail();
}
```